# jquery Ajax working on chrome but not on firefox, using jquery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have not encountered anything like this ever before. I've always worked on Jquery Ajax and manage to make them work on all browsers but this issue have me stomped.

here is my JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('#crmgrpsub').click(function () {
            var status;
            var crmgrpid = $("#crmgrpid").val();

            if($("#crmsecured").attr("checked")){
                status = 1;
            }else{
                status = 0;
            }
            // alert(status);
            if(status == 0){
                alert("hello");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "securezones/ajax_zoneoperations.php",
                    data: "zid="+crmgrpid+"&action=delete",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am able to alert Hello on all browsers so the issue lies on $.ajax, this works fine with chrome but on firefox I get a red on firebug on the post request of ajax, any reason why it would not submit on FF 21.0? or this could be some other ajax interfering with this what is the best way for me to check if it is really just another ajax call messing with my current ajax?

Thank you

Comment: It's time to upgrade your jquery, no?!

Comment: Well, look at the request. Why is it red? wrong status code? did the post data get sent properly? does `crmgrpid` contain the same value in both firefox and chrome?

Comment: @roasted I can't do that right now, theres a lot of depreciated functions that will all go down hill if I decide to upgrade.

Comment: @KevinB thats the thing it doenst say much just shows its red, im not really a firefox fan so im not that into it. will try a different ajax request though to check if its that line of code that is wrong

Comment: Open the network tab and click on the request, the information there should be similar to what you see in chrome. You're looking for the request headers and the response headers.

Comment: So i just changed the ajax request to a jquery .html to see if it still work, and it does so it really is a request problem. @KevinB where is the network tab? i just inspect with firebug and go to console to see the error

Comment: click "Net" then make your request send, you'll then see them listed.

Comment: @KevinB https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795978 this was the error found when i click "Net" and processed the request

Comment: You should escape your dynamic param `var crmgrpid = encodeURIComponent($("#crmgrpid").val());`.